# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)

Tags: python, mysql, cron

I have a cron job which queries data from db and dumps into a csv file at the end of the day. I am using mysql database and python client. Cron job works fine for some days and then it crashes with an error

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306'(111 Connection refused)
```

my code

```
def job():
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = str(x.date() - datetime.timedelta(0))
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='',user='',
                                     password='',auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    cursor = connection.cursor()  
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE date = '%s'" % date)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    print(len(results)) 
    c = csv.writer(open('milo-'+date+'.csv', 'w'))
    try:
        headers = [header_list]
        c.writerow(i for i in headers)
        print('added headers')
        for x in results:
            c.writerow(x)
    except Exception as e:
        print('CSV generation failed')
        print(str(e))
```

If I re run the script it works fine for few days and then it crashes again. Can someone help me with my is it happening so?

Comment: Check that your MySQL server isn't crashing out.

Comment: Also use placeholder values. It's super easy, but important: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE date=%s", (date))` where you're not interpolating, you're letting the driver bind data for you.

Comment: no everything is fine at MySQL end.

Comment: It's clearly not fine if you're getting connection errors. *Something* is wrong here, and it's related to that port not being accessible.

Comment: Are you able to telnet to this port `telnet localhost 3306`?

Comment: there are other services and apis which use db. all those are fine,I guess there is a problem with this particular connection

Comment: It's to localhost which means it should work *if* the server is up. If the server craps out now and then, even briefly, it could cause a connection issue.